# What ID does a 17 year old need for domestic air travel?

Tags: usa, air-travel, minors

I am 17 and I do not have my driver's license yet, would that be a problem even though I am flying from state to state with my grandma?

Comment: Are you concerned with being able to get past the TSA checkpoint at the airport?

Comment: Don’t know whether you need it, but I would recommend an ID card that you can get at the same place as a driver’s license.  It does everything that a driver’s license except for the driving privilege.

Answer (score 5):

The Transport Security Administration (TSA) does not require children and teenagers under 18yo to carry identification.

The airline may have its own requirements, however. You should contact them for more information.

Once you're 18 you will need some identification. You can find a complete list of acceptable IDs on [the TSA web site](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification), along with the comments about children I have summarised above.

Comment: As you are not flying with your parents, your Gradma may need a letter-of-consent from BOTH your parents, authorising her to fly with you. This is a part of the anti-child-trafficking legislation laws in most countries. I appreciate you're almost an adult, and I don't know if the age-limit for self-travel in the US is lower than 18.

Comment: @CSM there's no need for that in the US.